# How to reorder data based on the "next" field

Tags: python, django

Hi I am programming using python and I want to display the list in correct order based on `next` field. I have a model which looks like:

Task()

```
id     name     next
1      task1     3
2      task2     0
3      task3     2
```

I do not know how to display it because I only know the basic

```
taskList = Task.objects.all()
```

so when I display it, it should look like

```
task1
task3
task2
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
Task.objects.all().order_by('next')
```

to reverse the order use '-next' instead.